# Need to scroll this. Dont know how to do it

Tags: c++

This is the code:

```
for (i = 0; i < max; i++) { //RIGHT-SHIFT
    cout << "                 "; //blank space before padding

    cout << "***"; //left padding
    for (j = i; j >= 0; j--) { // this prints one more * than the last line (left side)
        cout << "**";
    }
    for (k = 0; k < width; k++) { // print the white space
        cout << " ";
    }
    for (j = max - i; j > 0; j--) { // this prints one less than the last line (right side)
        cout << "**";
    }
    cout << "***\n";//right padding
}

for (i = max; i > 0; i--) { //LEFT-SHIFT
    cout << "                 "; //blank space before padding
    cout << "***"; //left padding
    for (j = i; j >= 0; j--) { // this prints one more * than the last line (left side)
        cout << "**";
    }
    for (k = 0; k < width; k++) { // print the white space
        cout << " ";
    }
    for (j = max - i; j > 0; j--) { // this prints one less than the last line (right side)
        cout << "**";
    }
    cout << "***\n";//right padding
}
```

It looks something like 
[image]

I want the first row to have 4 - 19 instead of 5- 20. How do i change it?

Answer (score 0):

Print out one fewer asterisk in your initial `cout << "***"` in each outer loop.  ie. do `cout << "**"` instead for your "left padding".  That will make all the rows narrower by one asterisk, but will preserve the overall pattern, which is what I presume you wanted.